# Resize fontawesome icons all over project

Tags: font-awesome

I wanted to use font-awesome with vuetify instead of the material icons they use as default, however the font-awesome icons are all very big and look clunky with the vuetify components, is there a way to make them smaller overall, maybe with `font-size` or something?

This is an example of what I mean, the icon on top is ok but the password eye looks terrible so big.

[image]

In this case of the eye icon I can't resize it like I normally could, because of the way it's set up. They are just called in the v-text-view, so I can't set up a font size or anything.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="form.password"
    :rules="rules.passwordRules"
    label="Password"
    :append-icon="show ? 'fas fa-eye fa-xs' : 'fas fa-eye-slash fa-xs'"
    :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
    @click:append="show = !show"
    clearable
    required></v-text-field>
```

Comment: `font-size` should work: `.fas {font-size: 16px;}`

Comment: @Ludolfyn Thats works great! Thanks

Comment: Awesome @Nancy! I'm going to post it in an answer so you can mark this Q as answered =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-size` should work:

```
.fas {font-size: 16px;}
```